# Custom SignalR back plane implementation for unique pay load

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, real-time, scale

we are in a situation where millions of connections (approximately 30 million) will be connected to application. (SignalR Hubs)
however 90% of them will be idle and main operation is  **server push**  to **specific client** thus i need to implement a scale out mechanism.

so i came across [this fantastic talk](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/3-502) on channel 9 by Damian Edwards where he states that current implementations of backplanes for SignalR is very limited and in scenarios like mine a Custom scale out is needed specifically in server push situation. (at 58:29 of above talk)

after spending many hours in web, i could not find any clear guidance on how to implement a custom backplane which suits my need.

**i would like to know how signalR back plane internally works** and basically how a backplane works in general. so i can implement my own one.

any help, blog post etc.. is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is that still relevant (the video)? That's from MS Build 2013 (3 years old). Also, the source code is on GitHub. You are free to fork/clone the repo and read through the source code. That's what I did

Comment: of course it`s relevant (the Redis implementation is still the same). may you explane about how the back plane works as answer. as far as i know a socket has server afinity) thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to reiterate the source code here for you. From there you can see that the implementation varies by provider. If you have a specific question about how SignalR keeps track of user's connections across multiple servers using a backplane, for example, that would be on topic here.

Comment: that`s exactly what i wanted (which i failed to put in question obviously). How signalr keeps track of connections across multiple servers?

Answer (score 1):

Please read [this piece of documentation](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr), specifically the piece regarding *Implementation*.

**TL;DR** -

> When a message is sent, it goes to the backplane, and the backplane sends it to every server. When a server gets a message from the backplane, it puts the message in its local cache. The server then delivers messages to clients from its local cache.

Comment: thanks, how to implement a back plane that supports filtered subscription? you got any link or any piece of doc about it which i missed?

Comment: What do you mean by *filtered subscription* ?

Comment: the problem with current implementation as you said "sends the message to every server" which basically makes it useless in large scale. (as the SignalR author has already stated).

Comment: Unless you're using sticky sessions, the user could technically be on multiple servers at the same time (assuming you're using a load balancer)

Comment: thanks for your time. lets say i am going to push a message to 10 million users, at that point every server will do that. while i could filter out the operation only to one server. i got the word "filtered subscription" from Damian Edwards in talk which i mentioned in the question.

Comment: In the article I linked from Microsoft, they say that a Server broadcast (exactly what you just said) works well for SignalR + Backplane.

Comment: yeh you`r right, but it dose not work in high scale (it is super limited) you can either test it (which i did and got huge bandwidth waste and latency) or watch the talk.

Comment: Aside from getting into a queue and processing messages to broadcast in a batch, I think I can't answer your question any more than I already have. Hopefully someone else with more experience sees this thread and has a solution for you.